# backbone.js dry search results model and collection

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I'm trying to create a dry search results model and collection for backbone so that no matter what I'm searching for in the app, we use the same model/collection and occasionally might call a different view.

My Model and controller are very simple

```
Myapp.Models.Search = Backbone.Model.extend();

Myapp.Collections.Search = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Myapp.Models.Search
});
```

I then populate the url value to get the correct requests and parameters in the view

```
Myapp.Views.SearchResults = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: 'div#results',

 initialize: function(){
     Myapp.results = new Backbone.Collection.Search;
     Myapp.results.url = this.model.search_type+'/'+this.model.data; //this holds the search query
     Myapp.results.fetch({
               success: function(){alert('got result')},
               error: function(){alert('that is not good!');}
       });
   }
```

without 'fetch', everything is fine, but when I include fetch, the fetch is made, the results are returned, but I get the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function          in backbone.js:23
```

I've checked the response, and it is valid JSON. When I output the Myapp.results to the console, I see the collection, but it is still empty. Neither the error not success are getting gtriggered.

----------------update------------------------
as per the comments, I've divided up line 23, and found that the error is being returned in this line

```
a=new this.model(a,b),
```

If I am understanding what this line does, could this issue be because the response collection only has one model being returned? I would hope that wouldn't cause the issue, you should be able to have a collection with 1 or less models in it.

--------------update--------------------------

So I remove the reference to `model` within the collection, and now I don't get the error. So in some ways, this is resolved, but it shouldn't be. Is there a reason why up to now I've always defined the model associated with the collection?

Comment: Use the debugger to step into fetch and see exactly which object backbone expects to be a function is undefined and that will probably point you clearly at the bug. If you paste the relevant section of backbone.js (need your exact version and much easier with unminified source) around line 23, we can figure it out from that as well.

Comment: And you probably want to use a non-minified version of `backbone.js` while tracking this problem down.

Comment: I've updated the question with the offending bit of code in backbone.js

Comment: Well, do you people also think there is one `}` extra after `error` callback ? Or is the content not properly formatted ? Or may be something wrong with my understanding :-/

Comment: You're right @Cyclone, but that wasn't the error. I've tried running it just with `.fetch()`, and I still have the error. I've run the response through jsonlint, and the formatting is correct, and the model has an id, which I believe is the only requirement for backbone collections.

Comment: what happens if you do, from the console, `foo = new MyApp.Models.Search()`? and what do you get logged when you do `console.log(MyApp.Models.Search)` (note there are no brackets at the end). The first should work and the second should return a function...

Comment: @Tallmaris, the first one I get a `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_reset'`, you are correct, the second returns the function.

Comment: Mmmm... from the source code: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-75, `_reset()` is a Collection private method and it's strange it is being called when creating a Model. Try stepping through the code, from the `new` call and see where the path is leading. Use the link as a reference... Maybe also try something like `var foo = new Backbone.Model()` just to see that everything is working as expected.